# How do I resolve an IP Adress from a host name on windows phone 8.1?

Tags: c#, callback, windows-phone-8.1, ip-address, hostname

How do I write a method that resolves the hostname which is entered as a parameter that returns an IP Address?

I searched for a way to do this and both of the sites I found have similar solutions

[WP7 Mango - How to get an IP address for a given hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800851/wp7-mango-how-to-get-an-ip-address-for-a-given-hostname)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5c07b344-be5b-4358-beb1-abea581ca2bb/how-to-resolve-a-hostname-to-an-ip-address-in-windows-phone-8?forum=wpdevelop

```
public void DnsLookup(string hostname)
{
    var endpoint = new DnsEndPoint(hostname, 0);
    DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync(endpoint, OnNameResolved, null);  
}

private void OnNameResolved(NameResolutionResult result)
{
    IPEndPoint[] endpoints = result.IPEndPoints;
    // Do something with your endpoints
}
```

I am having trouble using the soluitons.

I can't change the return type of the OnNameResolved and the ResolveHostNameAsync requires a NameResolutionCallback.

So how do I make a method that returns the IP Adress?

Answer (score 1):

Given the limited capabilities by the .NET Framework here, you have to write an asynchronous approach here:

```
public static class NetworkHelper
{
    public event EventHandler<DnsLookupCompletedEventArgs> DnsLookupCompleted;

    public void DnsLookupAsync(string hostname)
    {
        var endpoint = new DnsEndPoint(hostname, 0);
        DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync(endpoint, OnNameResolved, null);  
    }

    private void OnNameResolved(NameResolutionResult result)
    {
        IPEndPoint[] endpoints = result.IPEndPoints;
        var args = new DnsLookupCompletedEventArgs(endpoints);
        if (DnsLookupCompleted != null)
            DnsLookupCompleted(this, args);
    }
}
```

Whereas `DnsLookupCompletedEventArgs` would look like this, so you can handle the endpoints later on:

```
public class DnsLookupCompletedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public IPEndPoint[] Endpoints { get; private set; }

    public DnsLookupCompletedEventArgs(IPEndPoint[] endpoints)
    {
        Endpoints = endpoints;
    }
}
```